# How to extract ObjectId to timestamp using mongodb function gettimestamp() in Pentaho Data Integrator

Tags: mongodb, pentaho, pdi

I'm trying to modify my ETL flow on Pentaho, which is mongodb to oracle. I'd like to change it to incremental flow so I need a create date.

In mongodb there is a column named _id which has ObjectId and it gives you timestamp with getTimestamp() function.

ObjectId.getTimestamp()

How can use it on the json path though?

Here is ss from pentaho;

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MClgl.png)

I tried this $._id.getTimestamp() and it give me null value.

Comment: Please don't paste screenshots, use formatted text. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551

Comment: According to your screenshot the data type is **String** rather than **ObjectId**. Maybe you first need to convert to proper `ObjectId`

Comment: If the String contains the hexadecimal representation of an ObjectID, the first 8 characters will be the epoch time in hex.

Answer (score 0):

```
var objectIdFromDate = function (date) {
    return Math.floor(date.getTime() / 1000).toString(16) + "0000000000000000";
};

var dateFromObjectId = function (objectId) {
    return new Date(parseInt(objectId.substring(0, 8), 16) * 1000);
};
```

Source and credits:
SteveRdiout
https://github.com/SteveRidout/mongo-object-time